# CSS Class doesn't seem to be alive

Tags: html, css

I've been giving up for months. The CSS class "specifics" just doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Code

```css
 .characteristic-product-comparator {
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-bottom:15px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        border-bottom:1px #211E33 solid;
    }
     div.characteristic-product-comparator .specifics {
        font-weight:normal !important;
        font-size:16px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="characteristic-product-comparator">
    <p>Résolution<br> <span class="specifics">2160p</span></p>
    <p>Micro<br> <span class="specifics">Oui</span></p>
    <p>Caractéristiques<br> <span class="specifics">Zoom HD X5, Windows Hello, HDR, enregistrement 4K, suppression arrière plan.</span></p>
    </div>
```

- I tried to be more specific in the CSS file like : **div.characteristic-product-comparator p span.specifics** but it didn't work.
- I also tried to rename .specifics by .bobby but it didn't work also.

This class on the other hand :

```
.characteristic-product-comparator
```

is working fine.

The **span class="specifics"** just doesn't seem to inherit the class… Why does ".specifics" don't show any effect on the HTML ?

P.S: I'm on **WordPress** and I'm using **Divi**. I don't know if the Divi CSS files can be linked to this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the desired output you are trying to get? `specificity` alone is not enough to overwrite `!important` is that's what you are trying to do. If you want to overwrite the `!important` style you will need to be more `specific` and add the `!important` keyword.

Comment: Right-click, Inspect it (Chrome) and see if that class `.specifics` is being pulled through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBinFeVZz0E

Comment: Since the CSS works fine in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/vk1g3tjc/). We won't be able to help you more, you should check the code like @David suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, I'm using Safari and when I inspect, there is only .characteristic-product-comparator that is being pulled through. Not ".specifics"…

Comment: you could improve the HTML (also helps with SEO) by making the headings one of  `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4` ... and remove the `<br>` s. That would also simplify the CSS.

Comment: Can you please try accessing from some other browser also? I mean Chrome or Firefox and see if they are also showing the same problem?

Comment: I tried also on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/walkys/fg70b4pc/12/), and it does not work for me…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special character at "Special" make CSS don't working.
I am surprised and funny with this finding :>>

[image]

```css
 .characteristic-product-comparator {
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-bottom:15px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        border-bottom:1px #211E33 solid;
    }
     div.characteristic-product-comparator .specifics {
        font-weight:normal !important;
        font-size:16px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="characteristic-product-comparator">
    <p>Résolution<br> <span class="specifics">2160p</span></p>
    <p>Micro<br> <span class="specifics">Oui</span></p>
    <p>Caractéristiques<br> <span class="specifics">Zoom HD X5, Windows Hello, HDR, enregistrement 4K, suppression arrière plan.</span></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an issue with your theme's CSS or an issue with Safari.

More importantly however, simplifying the HTML may eliminate the need for any awkward CSS.

```
.characteristic-product-comparator {
    font-size:18px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:1px #211E33 solid;
}
.characteristic-product-comparator p {
    font-size:16px;
}

<div class="characteristic-product-comparator">
   <h2>Résolution</h2><p>2160</p>
   <h2>Micro</h2><p>Oui</p>
   <h2>Caractéristiques</h2><p>Zoom HD X5, Windows Hello, HDR, enregistrement 4K, suppression arrière plan.</p>
</div>
```